# Latex ist generating an useless empty page after my appendix

Tags: latex

I'm using Latex with my university's template. From my main.tex I am calling

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
%%\usepackage[abgabe]{bhtThesis}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
  literate={ö}{{\"o}}1
           {ä}{{\"a}}1
           {ü}{{\"u}}1
           {Ö}{{\"O}}1
           {Ä}{{\"A}}1
           {Ü}{{\"U}}1
           {ß}{{\ss}}1
}



\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}

\usepackage{trsym}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{kisgrey}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\usepackage[nolinks]{qrcode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\typeout{-----------------------------------------------------------}
\typeout{----> main.tex ---- Zentrales Dokument---------------------}
\typeout{-----------------------------------------------------------}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendix}
  \input{anhang.tex}
\clearpage
\end{appendix}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur- und Quellenverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
\bibliography{bhtThesis}

\end{document}
```

and at the end of my anhang.tex is a useless empty page, refering to my anhang (the page header refers to my anhang?

```
\chapter{Dateien}

Alle relevanten Dateien, die für die Funktionsfähigkeit der dargestellten Anwendung erforderlich sind, wurden der Arbeit beigelegt. Dabei handelt es sich um die folgenden Dateien:

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{kis\_v100.db\_prefs} Datei für die Erweiterung der primären Datenbankschlüssel
\item \texttt{kis\_v100.obda} beinhaltet die Zuordnungen zwischen Datenbank und Ontologie
\item \texttt{kis\_v100.owl} ist die Datei der Ontologie
\item \texttt{kis\_v100.properties} beispielhafte Darstellung des Verbindungsdokuments für die Datenbank
\item \texttt{kis\_v100.q} beinhaltet die SPARQL-Abfragen
\item \texttt{kis\_v100.pdf} ist die Ausgabedatei dieser Arbeit
\end{itemize}
\clearpage
```

What can I do to find the reason for this useless empty page? There are no warning about badboxes or something similar.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: I updated the main.tex-code and it should run as it does on my pc.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (but obviously the example neither cites anything nor does it provide the bib file). Just a guess: the two `\clearpage`s in a row might have something to do with it or is the empty page on an even page number?  Books only start chapters on odd pages ...

Comment: yes it is. How do I prevent it?

Comment: Try the `openany` documentclass option

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks a lot. I should have read more about the documentclass book I am using.
I think it is a remarkable coincidence that all my other chapters started on an odd page.

Comment: Good thing that the last chapter decided to give you the opportunity to get to know a new option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I used the documentclass book, all chapters start on an odd page. And so my "anhang" produced a single free page to start on odd page, thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.
So I just had to set my documentclass to `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openany]{book}`. And openany fixed everything for me.